# Places API Not Working

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to use the **Google Places API**. However, I am always getting errors.

[image: Console]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mapthingie">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaKEY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaAPIKEY" />

        <activityhttps://stackoverflow.com/tags
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my LogCat, I am getting this error:

> PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID

though, as you can see, I am using a valid key. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to add a new API key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are two different keys in `Manfiest.xml`

try to remove the one inside the `application` tag.

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaAPIKEY" />
```

Here is the edited one, copy and paste and try.

If it din't work, renew your `API_Key` and then replace it .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mapthingie">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaKEY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**cheers!**

Comment: It worked once, but my computer shut down and even though I tried these steps again it is not working.

Comment: None, other than PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID.

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding the same API key which you are getting from the website, if the error still resists, restart your IDE or your computer.

Comment: as far as I understand, this error happens for two reasons, either you are not using the latest API key which you have asked on the website, or Google Place API isn't enabled properly.

Comment: Makes sense - it was working previously though, which makes it confusing. Now, the requests are no longer showing up in the dashboard. I have double checked to make sure that I am using the latest API key and that the Places API is enabled properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167518/discussion-between-vicky-and-niamatullah-bakhshi).